# How do I prevent the creation of pointers when I copy a property in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In coffeescript, if I do something like

```
foo = {}
foo.prop = bar.prop
```

what happens is that if I manipulate `foo.prop` afterwards, `bar.prop` will also change (ie: js is not copying the object, but just creating a pointer to it).

How do I prevent this behavior from happening? Is cycling trough the object and copying field by field the only solution?

Thanks!

Comment: That's just how JS works, if `prop` is an object then both will be the same. So yes, copying the object is the solution.

Comment: Whatever utility belt library you're using (such as lo-dash) will usually have functions for shallow and deep cloning.